# what's the best way to send message to different multiple queues?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a List of Queues, such as [queueA,queueB,...queueX]. And this set needs to change dynamiclly according to a property file.

And for each message, it should be send to some queues in this set, with some rules.

What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reviewing my history questions and see this.So just answer it in in case someone else will also have this demand.

I choose apache-camel's recipient-list(http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) to do this, the destination can be easily defined in the java DSL.